# How to use Sum in an IF Statement in VBA

Tags: vba, if-statement, sum

All i'm trying to do is find out if a range is > 0 using VBA but i'm having trouble with summing the range, when I run it I get the error 438

Here is my Code;

```
If cbAC.Value = True And Sheets("Cost Sheet").Sum(Range(Cells(25, 4), Cells(30, 4))).Value > 0 Then
```

Comment: [`WorksheetFunction.Sum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-sum-method-excel) - there's no `Sheets.Sum` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum (Sheets("Cost Sheet").Range(Cells(25, 4), Cells(30, 4)))
```